# WF4.0: Workflow designer for a Custom Code Activity - Is MVVM a good idea?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

By default ActivityDesigner set its DataContext to "this" (the ActivityDesigner itself). The ModelItem type and is available through the ModelItem property and represents the Activity you are doing a designer for.

Would it be a good idea to use MVVM for ActivityDesigner ? I don't think so but I couldn't find any article on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Activity is your ViewModel.  And the ModelItem is where you mix in what does not exist within the Activity.

The ModelItem wraps your ViewModel to provide for all the UI facilities that do not need to exist within the Activity itself, such as undo/redo and change notification.

It also, and possibly more importantly, provides for **attached properties** which you can use to mix into your Activity ViewModel-ish facilities that do not and should not exist within your Activity.